# Autocorrelation plot - overlap axis (visual bug)

Tags: python, pandas, plot, autocorrelation

I am having a strange bug with the autocorrelation plot of the pandas library.

```
from pandas.plotting import autocorrelation_plot
[... other stuff ...]
def autocorrelation(self,data):
        # Plot the autocorrelation of the given data series
        # The autocorr. plot shows the autocorrelation value of original data over all lagged sample (lag = 0, lag = 1,...)
        # lag = [0 to N-1] where N = len(data) [example: len(data) = 1000 sample --> lag = [0,999]]
        print("Preparing plot for autocorrelation...")
        plt.figure(1)
        plt.title('Autocorrelation')
        autocorrelation_plot(data)
```

And That's what I get:

[image]

As you can see on the left (y-axis) there is an overlap of value. Do you know why?

Thanks